# Switching streams in RX: Sodium's equivalent of merge and switch in RX

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, sodium

How can the television channel problem as explained in this [talk](http://youtu.be/gaG3tIb3Lbk) at 31th minute be solved by RX ?

The problem expressed in Rx is as follows:

The are two television channels (`channel1` and `channel2`) which transmit a stream of images, plus a stream of `fuzz` which represents no channel or white noise.

There are two buttons which send events `eButton1` and `eButton2` when they are pressed.

These button presses should result in the respective channels being sent to the screen.

Each button press should be projected (mapped) into the respective channel, and then all channels combined into a selection stream as stream of streams which starts with the `fuzz` stream. Finally a switch operator sends the selected stream to the `screen`.

#### Question

What is the equivalent of Sodiums'switch and merge in RX?

Is it possible to solve it with pure higher order functions ? I.e. without using closures ? I don't see how that would be possible.

[image]

Comment: It's not up to the users reading this question to watch a video to figure out your question.  I'd suggest editing this into an actual question, then maybe it could be reopened.

Comment: @bluefeet I've ported the question in from the video on behalf of OP - I think it's useful enough to be worth reopening? I have an answer ready to post... :)

Comment: @JamesWorld: What is the question exactly? Shouldn't the OP be showing some effort in to solving the problem first before posting here?

Comment: @musefan - I thought I managed to port it well enough... no? I've donated the effort (shouldn't the question should be the target of the evaluation rather than the OP *per se*?), because I think the answer has educational value. I've seen enough Rx newbies struggle to write a few lines of code, so I'm happy to answer a theoretical question with concrete code here.

Comment: @JamesWorld: I know what you are saying, but I have seen meta posts before stating that SO is not meant to be a wiki. In situations like this I feel the question just ends up becoming a title/intro for a blog style post. I don't doubt the usefulness, I just didn't think it was how SO operates. I won't vote either way anymore, if it gets re-opened then so be it

Comment: @musefan OK. Seems quite specific to me though, and I do have a specific answer. Happy to let democracy rule... ;)

Comment: @jhegedus His criticism is valid... posting a video link is vulnerable to broken links, Meta is very clear on this point.

Comment: vulnerable yes but if it gets broken it can be fixed, a video is just like any other source of information, like a book, a picture.. or the internet... so any link is vulnerable to that, so we should copy the whole world into each post... funny :) I think someone is really ego tripping here still :) so I might just need to repost this question when he is sleeping :)

Comment: Maybe I can post this question to reddit?

Comment: I'm really curious about your answer James. Are you on reddit?

Comment: @James FYI, the question has been reopened now. BTW: [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284567/3764814).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229197(v=vs.103).aspx) and [Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.merge(v=vs.103).aspx) both exist in the core Rx library, so happily the code in the slides actually translates almost verbatim line for line into Rx.

The [`Switch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229197(v=vs.103).aspx) operator works on a stream of streams - in Rx this is a type `IObservable<IObservable<T>>`.

Switch flattens this stream of streams sending only the most recent stream to it's output, so you end up with an `IObservable<T>`.

See the C# sample below. I've re-used the variable names in the talk as far as possible, so this should be easy to follow.

The only thing that's (very slightly) different is the `hold` function is replaced with the Rx equivalent `StartWith`.

Include nuget package `Rx-Main` and run this as a console app. The code subscribes to the `screen` stream and starts rendering frames from the "Fuzz" channel to the console. It will prompt you for a channel number. Enter 1 or 2 and you'll see the output switch to frames from the corresponding channel.

```
// helper method to create channels
private static IObservable<string> CreateChannelStream(
    string name, CompositeDisposable disposables)
{
    // this hacks together a demo channel stream -
    // a stream of "frames" for the channel
    // for simplicity rather than using images, I use a string
    // message for each frame
    // how it works isn't important, just know you'll get a
    // message event every second
    var channel = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                            .Select(x => name + " Frame: " + x)
                            .Publish();
    disposables.Add(channel.Connect());
    return channel;
}

public static void Main()
{       
    // for cleaning up the hot channel streams
    var disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    // some channels
    var fuzz = CreateChannelStream("Fuzz", disposable);
    var channel1 = CreateChannelStream("Channel1", disposable);
    var channel2 = CreateChannelStream("Channel2", disposable);

    // the button press event streams
    var eButton1 = new Subject<Unit>();
    var eButton2 = new Subject<Unit>();

    // the button presses are projected to
    // the respective channel streams
    // note, you could obtain the channel via a function call here
    // if you wanted to - to keep it close to the slides I'm not.
    var eChan1 = eButton1.Select(_ => channel1);
    var eChan2 = eButton2.Select(_ => channel2);

    // create the selection "stream of streams"
    // an IObservable<IObservable<string>> here
    // that starts with "fuzz"
    var sel = Observable.Merge(eChan1, eChan2).StartWith(fuzz);

    // flatten and select the most recent stream with Switch
    var screen = sel.Switch();

    // subscribe to the screen and print the frames
    // it will start with "fuzz"
    disposable.Add(screen.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine));

    bool quit = false;

    // a little test loop
    // entering 1 or 2 will switch
    // to that channel
    while(!quit)
    {
        var chan = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (chan.ToUpper())
        {
            case "1":
                // raise a button 1 event
                eButton1.OnNext(Unit.Default);
                break;
            case "2":
                // raise a button 2 event
                eButton2.OnNext(Unit.Default);
                break;  
            case "Q":
                quit = true;
                break;                
        }
    }         

    disposable.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is really nice. Thanks. Do you happen to know how `Switch`, `Merge` are called in RXScala ?

Comment: According to  scaladoc these methods exist verbatim in RXScala too, cool! Thanks again!

Comment: Observable.Merge(eChan1, eChan2) - doesn't create stream of streams, it merges two streams

Comment: Yes, you misinterpreted my comment. eChan1 is a stream of streams (each event in the stream is itself a channel, a stream of images). eChan2 is also stream of streams. Therefore the result of the merge is still a stream of streams.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the right kind of thing:

```
IObservable<System.Drawing.Image> fuzz = ...
IObservable<System.Drawing.Image> channel1 = ...
IObservable<System.Drawing.Image> channel2 = ...

IObservable<string> eButton1 = ... // produces string "eButton1" when clicked
IObservable<string> eButton2 = ... // produces string "eButton2" when clicked

var output =
(
    from button in eButton1.Merge(eButton2).StartWith("")
    select
        button == "eButton1"
            ? channel1
            : (button == "eButton2"
                ? channel2 
                : fuzz)
).Switch();
```

Comment: This one seems to have a closure in it.  The accepted solution does not use  higher order functions that are not referentially transparent.